# Android Studio Project doesn't open new activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have tried with intent to open a new activity for several days now, but when I open in the AVD, it crashes. Where`s the problem?

```
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(v -> openRegister());

public void openRegister() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Register.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Can you share logs ?

Comment: Did you included your activity in xml file?

Comment: is Register class delared in your manifest

Comment: It is declared in the manifest as <activity android:name=".Register"/>, but there's nothing else referencing the register activity in the main activity. Is the problem there?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

See the Google docs on this here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#BuildIntent

Comment: Please include the .java file for your Register activity.  I think you'll be inflating the activity_main XML. That's the only reason I can think that you'll be seeing the wrong activity load up on this call.

Comment: Register activity is empty. What do you mean with inflating?

Comment: In your onCreate in your register activity, you need to make sure the setContentView(R.layout.register_activity); is called.